# C# - Resources.GetDrawable is obsolete in Android Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android

I implemented `Resources.GetDrawable` in andrdoid Xamarin. The program works, but if I clicked the button implementing the `Resources.GetDrawable` the program force close. Here's my code:

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
drawView = FindViewById<DrawingView>(Resource.Id.drawing);
LinearLayout paintLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.paint_colors);
currPaint = (ImageButton)paintLayout.GetChildAt(0);
currPaint.SetImageDrawable(Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.paint_pressed));
```

The `Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.paint_pressed` got green underlined(Xamarin in Visual Studio 2015). The log message returned exception:

> Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException
>
> 'Resources.GetDrawable(int)' is obsolete: 'deprecated'

For Java version the solution is by using one of these 3:

```
ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.name, null);
//or
ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.name);
//or
ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.name, anotherTheme);
```

What is the version for C# Android Xamarin?, Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change to `SetImageResource` like this

```
currPaint.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.paint_pressed);
```

Comment: It seems work, the green underlined is gone. But the button still force the app to close. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

```
var currPaint= ContextCompat.GetDrawable(this,Resource.Drawable.paint_pressed);
        currPaint.SetBounds(0, 0, 60, 60);
```

> This is what i have implimented in my project even i had same problem.Hope this helps! @Jake

Answer (score 6):

(for a **Xamarin Forms** project)

When I need to get a drawable from my **.Droid** project I usually use the following line:

```
Control.Background = Context.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.ResourceName);
```